# Motorola EMDK - Possible to have multiple sets of decoder parameters for I2OF5?

Tags: compact-framework, barcode, motorola-emdk

I am developing an application that needs to be able to scan multiple lengths/types of I2of5 barcodes.  The longer barcodes are 14 digits long, and the shorter ones are either 4 or 10 long.

I set to parameters of the I2OF5 decoder to allow this:

```
Barcode2 symbolBarcode2 = new Barcode2(Symbol.Barcode2.Devices.SupportedDevices[0]);
symbolBarcode2.Config.Decoders.I2OF5.MinLength = 4;
symbolBarcode2.Config.Decoders.I2OF5.MaxLength = 14;
```

I am having an issue with the scanner decoding partial scans of the longer barcodes.  Setting the Min and Max to 14 would fix this, but would no longer allow scanning of the shorter barcodes.

The 14 digit barcodes use a USS check digit.  If I turn on the USS check digit scheme in the I2of5 parameter, it solves the issue since a partial scan would almost never have the correct check digit.  But the 10 and 4 digit barcodes do not use a check digit, so they no longer scan.

Is there a way to have more than one set of I2of5 parameters?  Then I could create one with a Min and Max length of 14 with USS turned on, and another with a Min and Max of 10 with USS turned off, and a third with a Min and Max of 4, also with USS turned off.

I believe the Intermec API allows this, having multiple sets of active parameters, but could not find a way to do it in the Motorola EMDK.  I am using the .Net EMDK 2.7.

Comment: As i know, there is no way to do it with EMDK .Net

Answer (score 0):

It is simpler to drop a TextBox control onto your device's Form, make sure it has focus, then either handle the TextChanged event or add a timer to read the TextBox's Text property every 500 milliseconds.

The two events (Timer Tick and TextBox TextChanged) both have the same signature, so you can even wire both up to the same event!

```
private const bool USETIMER = true;
private const int TIMER_MS = 500;
private System.Windows.Forms.Timer m_timer;
private TextBox txtBarcode;

public Form1() {
  InitializeComponent();
  if (USETIMER) {
    m_timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
    m_timer.Interval = TIMER_MS;
    m_timer.Tick += new EventHandler(Barcode_Check);
    m_timer.Enabled = true;
  } else {
    txtBarcode.TextChanged += new EventHandler(Barcode_Check);
  }
}

private void Barcode_Check(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtBarcode.Text)) {
    // Process your barcode
  }
}
```

You don't need to use their SDK at all.

Comment: I don't have any issues getting the data that is scanned.  I assume you would use the "Wedge" application with your code to actually get the data from the scanner.  I would have the same parameter issues with the Wedge.  It lets you edit code parameters just like the SDK.  But you can only have one set of parameters for the I2OF5 code.